# CreatedById is Undefined When Trying to Display Custom Object's Field Values in Salesforce LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

To get values of both CreatedById and CreatedDate, I used **getFieldDisplayValue** in my javascript file. After getting both values, I concatenate both values and displayed it in html. But when I check the value, only the CreatedDate displays the expected output, while CreatedById returns a null value. I would like to ask for your help regarding this issue.

**transactionsLWC.html**

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-theme_default">  
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Transaction__c" record-id={recordId} layout-type="Full" mode="view">
            <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
            <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap"> 
                    <div if:true={fscalctool.data}>   
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">  
                            <label class = "slds-var-m-right_small slds-var-m-bottom_medium">Transaction Detail</label>      
                            <p>{createdByAndDateTime}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>   
            </div>  
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </div>
</template>
```

**transactionsLWC.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldDisplayValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CREATEDBYID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Transaction__c.CreatedById';
import CREATEDDATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Transaction__c.CreatedDate';

const fields = [CREATEDBYID_FIELD, CREATEDDATE_FIELD];

export default class TransactionsLWC extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectname;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    transaction;

    get createdById() {
        return getFieldDisplayValue(this.transaction.data, CREATEDBYID_FIELD);
    }

    get createdDate() {
        return getFieldDisplayValue(this.transaction.data, CREATEDDATE_FIELD);
    }

    get createdByAndDateTime() {
        return `${this.createdById},${this.createdDate}`;
    }
}
```

My expected value does not match the actual value.

Following is an example:

**Expected:** `retailuser,10/19/2020,5:39 AM`

**Actual:** `null,10/19/2020,5:39 AM`